# Retrieving an entry archive with Stash

Tags: stash, low-yearly-archives

Trying to build an archive with **Stash** & **Low Yearly Archive**, but not getting it to work as I need. The result that I get with the code below is:

```
 - 2013
 - 2012
```

Everything within the nested list is not getting set it seems. Can you help spot what I am missing?

**Setting the list with:**

```
      {exp:stash:set_list name="yearly-archive" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
            {exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" start_month="1" status="not closed" sort="desc" dynamic="off"}                  
                {stash:year}{year}{/stash:year}
                {stash:year_count}{year_count}{/stash:year_count}
                {stash:total_years}{total_years}{/stash:total_years}                    
                {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="news_months_{year}" parse_tags="yes"}
                    {months}
                        {stash:num_entries}{num_entries}{/stash:num_entries}
                        {stash:month}{month}{/stash:month}
                        {stash:month_short}{month_short}{/stash:month_short}
                        {stash:month_num}{month_num}{/stash:month_num}
                    {/months}
                {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
            {/exp:low_yearly_archives}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

**Retrieving with:**

```
 {exp:stash:get_list name="yearly-archive" parse_tags="yes"}
 {if year_count == '1'}<ul>{/if}
      <li>
      {year}
      <ul>  
      {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="news_months_{year}" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
           <li>
           {if num_entries != 0}
                <a href="{path=blog/archive}{year}/{month_num}/" title="{num_entries} entries in {month} {year}">{month_short}</a>
           {if:else}
                {month_short}
           {/if}
           </li>
      {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
      </ul>
 </li>
 {if year_count == total_years}</ul>{/if}
 {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

When adding output="yes" to the set_list & set_list:nested tags the outer tag outputs as expected:

```
 year|=|2013|&|year_count|=|1|&|total_years|=|2|+|year|=|2012|&|year_count|=|2|&|total_years|=|2
```

The inner (nested tag) outputs nothing...

Thanks for taking a gander!

Comment: Have u tried just using the low archives tag to make sure your output is proper ? Basically leave stash out and it works ?

Comment: Yes, I have it currently working without stash. Using Low's basic example. But me trying to be clean and consistant, I'd love to separate the viewmodel from the templates.

Comment: Have you tried setting `output="yes"` on the `set_list` tags? That's always handy for debugging as it lets you  see what's being saved where.

Comment: Output on the outer list outputs as expected. (I will attach on original post.) The nested tag outputs nothing. As I understand, the {months} tag pair is a loop right?

Comment: Looks like it should be, yep. How about if you disable/comment out the `set_list` tags? That'll give you an idea of whether the `{months}` loop is working.

Comment: When I disable the nested list I get the years as expected but also the month of Jan is listed as well, so the loop is working since it is firing once per loop.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the `{months}` variable pair tagdata is removed from the template and appended to the output later on.

Please could you try this: instead of wrapping the inner `{exp:stash:set_list}` around the tag pair, use `{exp:stash:append_list}` *inside* the tag pair. Also, when you get the list, don't use `parse_tags="yes"` on either of the get_list tags - no further parsing is required at that point.